# fragmentManager.popBackStack(tag,0) doesn't work,

Tags: android, android-fragments

I use `replace()` and `addToBackStack(`) to show Fragment, and `popBackStack(tag,0)` to pop fragments. But before using `replace()`, I try to find out whether I can find the same fragment by `fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag()`, If found it, I will substitute `popBackStack(tag,0)` for `replace()`.

For example:
Activity start->replace the `AFragment` and add to BackStack->click button to replace the `BFragment` and add to BackStack->click button to `popBackStack(AFragment.tag,0)` to pop `BFragment` and go back to `AFragment`.

If, as excepted, it works with `replace()`, `pop()`, `replace()`, `pop()`, `replace()`, `pop()`..., but sometimes it works with `replace()`, `pop()`, {suddenly `fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag!=null`, so `pop()`, then no errors, it doesn't work}.

I try to debug, and find that the `mBackStack.size()` and `mActive.size()` in `FragmentManagerImp` are not equal.When I want to show `BFragment`, `mActive` contains A and B fragment, but `mBackStack` only contains `AFragment`(the transaction of replacing A fragment). Because I can find `BFragment` in `mActive`(using `fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag`), but can't find the transaction about `BFragment`, so `pop()` failed.

```
void replace() {
     String tag = fragment.getClass().getName();
            Fragment oldFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
            if (oldFragment != null) {
                try {
                    fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(tag, 0);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    LogUtils.e(e.getMessage());
                }
                return;
            }
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.layout_main_content, fragment, tag);
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(tag)) {
                transaction.addToBackStack(tag);
            }
            transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
```